Why there is no link to Area 51 discussion in all sites in Stack Exchange?
Why is there no link to  Area 51 discussion in all sites ?
Are there any other sites that are not included in all sites ?

https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ isn't there either I don't think.

@RobertLongson That's because cs50 SE is considered a 'special' SE site

The Area 51 Discussion Zone is the per-site meta for Area 51, and the list of sites in the Stack Exchange portal (https://stackexchange.com) does not include the per-site metas.
Worth to mention that Area 51 itself isn't listed as part of the sites, but rather mentioned below the list:



